# Node Telegraf callback button

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

For what we need to pass data to callback button in in simple keyboard (not inline), if thats doesn’t  matter?

Example:

```
const mainMenuKeyboard = Markup.InlineKeyboard([
  Markup.callbackButton('Add', 'addAction),
  ]).resize().extra();
```

Now, If I want to catch "addAddress" action, I can just do this:

```
bot.action('addAction',(ctx) => <WHATEVER>);
```

Everything works just fine&
But, when I want to use simple keyboard (not inline) in my project I cant catch  this action using "bot.action("addAction")" I have to use "bot.hears("Add")" :

```
const mainMenuKeyboard = Markup.keyboard([
  Markup.callbackButton('Add', 'addAction),
  ]).resize().extra();
```

Don’t  work

```
bot.action('addAction',(ctx) => <WHATEVER>);
```

Work

```
bot.hears('Add',(ctx) => <WHATEVER>);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using **Markup.callbackButton** (which is [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) on the Bot API) inside **Markup.keyboard**([ReplyKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup)).

According to Telegram Bot API docs, **Markup.keyboard**([ReplyKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup)) should contain **Array of Arrays** (not just an array BTW, fix that as well) of [KeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton). And **Markup.callbackButton**(which is [Inlinekeyboardbutton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) on the API) should be used for [InlineKeyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup) (not reply keyboard).

For more examples on how to use these on telegraf, [check this example out](https://github.com/feathers-studio/telegraf-docs/blob/master/examples/keyboard-bot.ts)

Comment: Thanks got it, but I have one more question. Whats the difference between Markup and Extra.markup. Which one I should use? In this example they use both of them, but If I will replace one to another nothing will change.

Comment: Extra object has a wider functionality scope (like controlling the message's notification mode, specifying "inReplyTo", setting parse_mode to HTML/markdown, and more..) while Markup is mainly related to Keyboards and Buttons. 
Having that in mind, Telegraf methods (like `reply()` and `replyWithHTML()`) accept **Extra** objects as the last argument (not Markup).  So if we use `Markup.` , we should call `.extra()` (to convert it to an **Extra**).  But we can use `Extra.markup` with the same effect (but we dont use `.extra()` in this case since we're operating on an Extra object)